# jQuery spinner button won't style active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style the active state of jQuery spinner buttons like this:

```
.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button:hover {
    background: #FF0;
}

.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button:active{
    background: #0FF;
}
```

Hover is working, but active is not. See jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kristinmboyer/xyb9fr35/1/).

Please excuse the ugly colors - just have those for simplicity's sake.

***Update:*** the issue is primarily in Firefox - it doesn't present itself in Chrome

Comment: What do you mean by active is not working? I see the button turning into black when clicked.

Comment: try background: #0FF !important;

Comment: @RinorDreshaj tried that and it didn't work - see link

Comment: @jamie_y the link was wrong - please look now

Comment: your code is working, but since it is a button it doesnt stay in active state

Comment: @RinorDreshaj So it's working in Chrome, but not Firefox I've noticed

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it in css tried some options but they dont work but i managed to solve it in jquery give it a try

```
$(".ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button").click(function(){
        //background you want to be in active state
        $(this).css("background","#111");


    //reverse the background in 0.1 second
        setTimeout(function(){        
              $(".ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button").css("background","#fff");
        }, 100); 
});
```

it works both in firefox and chrome, but you should remove the :active from css since it's going to work in chrome and you will get a mix of active state with the color specified in css and the one in jquery

Comment: Hmm. I can see what you're doing here, but I really want to try and find a css solution

Answer (score -1):

It looks like jQuery's background image is taking precedence over background color in Firefox. Try this:

```
.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button:hover {
    background-color: #FF0;
    background-image:none;
}

.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button:active{
    background-color: #0FF;
    background-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just replace :active pseudo-selector by :focus. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvWG5/92/

PD: I also replaced `type="submit"` by `type="button"` so I stay on the page.

---

Your new fiddle get fixed the same way. Checked: http://jsfiddle.net/xyb9fr35/2/

Same thing: replace `:active` by `:focus`and use `#testSpinner` as a selector instead of the class because that class is not in the DOM when the css is applied.

Comment: Ypu have change everything there. I can't say how uncool is that when someone already answered you. See the edited answer.

Comment: So I'm trying to style the buttons, not the input area :). It's working in Chrome, but not Firefox.